# Where does "catkin run_tests" get tests from?

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
catkin config --install
catkin build --limit-status-rate 0.1 --no-notify -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
catkin build --limit-status-rate 0.1 --no-notify --make-args tests
catkin run_tests
catkin_test_results build
```

After doing above for my package, it seems tests are run, even though they are not installed and only available in source space. Is it an expected behavior?

```
$ dpkg -p python-catkin-tools |grep Ver
Version: 0.3.0-1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220689/where-does-%22catkin-run_tests%22-get-tests-from?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, tests are built into the build space and executed there.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1